# MongoDB. Use cursor as value for $in in next query

Tags: mongodb, join, cursor

Is there a way to use the cursor returned by the previous query as a value for $in in the next query? For example, something like this:

```
var users = db.user.find({state:1})
var offers = db.offer.find({user:{$in:users}})
```

I think this can reduce the traffic between mongodb and client in case the client doesn't need user information at all, just offers. Am i wrong?

Comment: How would mongodb know which key you wish to search for with the `$in`?

Comment: It's not a problem to send additional options within the query to specify which key it should use. By default it can be _id as manual referencing recommends.

Comment: I mean it is an idea, and I mean intercollection locks (I believe) are planned for some time which could path way for this sort of thing and possibly even defining a string version of the cursor within the query doing SQL type joins, but that part scares me

Comment: You can't do a server-side join like this, but you could certainly implement similar logic in your app (fetch a list of IDs to use with an `$in` query).  Note that `$in` queries may not be overly efficient (particularly for a large number of values) as they do require skipping around the index to find matching documents.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want to do a join between two collections which Mongo doesn't support.  You can reduce the amount of data being transferred from the server by limiting the fields returned from the first query to only the unique user information (i.e. the _id) that you need to get data from the offers collection.

If you really just want to make one query then you should store more information in the offers collection.  For example, if you're trying to find offers for active users then you would store the active state of the user in the offers collection.

Comment: Yes, that's why I used tag 'join' in a question. The idea is that I can make a first query more сomplex using a bunch of fields and regexes without storing user data in other collections except references. In these cases I always have to perform two consecutive queries, but transfering of the results of the first query is not necessary neither for me nor for the mongodb itself.
I just want to understand could it be done now, will it be possible to do so in the future or it cannot be implemented for some technical reasons.

Answer (score 0):

To work from your comment:

> Yes, that's why I used tag 'join' in a question. The idea is that I
>   can make a first query more сomplex using a bunch of fields and
>   regexes without storing user data in other collections except
>   references. In these cases I always have to perform two consecutive
>   queries, but transfering of the results of the first query is not
>   necessary neither for me nor for the mongodb itself. I just want to
>   understand could it be done now, will it be possible to do so in the
>   future or it cannot be implemented for some technical reasons

As far as I understand it there is no immediate hurry to make this possible. Also the way it is coded atm will make this quite a big change to the way cursors work and are defined. A change big enough to possibly cause implementation breaks for other people. It is really a case of whether to set `safe` for inserts and updates for all future drivers. It is recognised that `safe` should be default but this will break implementation for other people who expect it the other way around.

It is rather inefficient if you don't require the results of the first query at all however since most networks are prepped with high traffic in mind and the traffic is cheap there hasn't been a demand to make it able to do chained queries server side in the cursor.

However subselects (which this basically is, it is selecting a set of rows based upon a sub selection of previous rows) have been on mongodb-user a couple of times and there might even be a JIRA for it somewhere, if not might be useful to make one.

As for doing it right now: there is no way.